# extract text between the 7th and 8th "/" characters

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have about 100,000 variables with a full path to the location of a relevant file.  The form is like this:

`/abc/def/ghij/klm/nopq/r/stu/vwx/yz`

The string I am looking for is the one between the 7th and 8th occurrence of "/", so `stu`.

Very grateful for any guidance.

Comment: And you want to use a regex rather than a field-based solution like `cut` or `awk` with the delimiter `/` because...?

Comment: I changed the subject heading to reflect your comment

Comment: OK and when you "variables" are these shell variables, or is the path list in a file? one per line or something else?

Comment: its a folder with 100k variables in it.  foreach variable, run script with output of format described above, and then extract the needed string and add it to a list.

Comment: Sorry I don't understand how a *folder* contains *variables*. Let's hope someone else can help you.

Comment: folder holds 100k files.  script converts each file name into its full path.  In that full path, I want the text between the 7th and 8th occurrence of "/"

Comment: OK so you want to post process the output of a script? if so, you should just be able to pipe it through `cut` or `awk` like `./yourscript | cut -d/ -f8` or `./yourscript | awk -F/ '{print $8}'`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have some source code where all of this variables have hard-coded values:

```
perl -nE 'say for m<(?:[/]([^/]+)[/]?){7}>g' src/*
```